# Transposing partially only some elements of a dataframe conditioned to matching two specific variables

Tags: r

How can I transpose only a part of a dataframe to another part of the same dataframe conditioned to some particular values of some cells in the dataframe?

I have a dataframe in R with the following structure:

```
str(df)

# 'data.frame': 20 obs. of  11 variables:
#  $ Code1    : int  1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 ...
#  $ SpeciesG1: chr  "Sp1" "Sp1" "Sp1" "Sp1" ...
#  $ Family   : chr  "Fam1" "Fam2" "Fam3" "Fam4" ...
#  $ Pct_feed : num  55.4 12.56 1.35 30.69 62.93 ...
#  $ Code2    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ SpeciesG2: chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
#  $ Fam1     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ Fam2     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ Fam3     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ Fam4     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ Fam5     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

The data looks as follows (this is only a small sample of a df that is several hundreds rows long):

```
df
#    Code1 SpeciesG1 Family Pct_feed Code2 SpeciesG2 Fam1 Fam2 Fam3 Fam4 Fam5
# 1      1       Sp1   Fam1    55.40     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 2      1       Sp1   Fam2    12.56     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 3      1       Sp1   Fam3     1.35     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 4      1       Sp1   Fam4    30.69     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 5      2       Sp1   Fam2    62.93     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 6      2       Sp1   Fam3    37.07     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 7      3       Sp2   Fam4    17.49     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 8      3       Sp2   Fam5    82.51     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 9      4       Sp2   Fam1    36.97     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 10     4       Sp2   Fam2    51.46     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 11     4       Sp2   Fam3    11.57     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 12     5       Sp3   Fam1    41.81     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 13     5       Sp3   Fam2     9.64     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 14     5       Sp3   Fam3    31.74     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 15     5       Sp3   Fam4     5.12     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 16     5       Sp3   Fam5    11.69     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 17     5       Sp4   Fam2    41.16     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 18     5       Sp4   Fam3    40.04     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 19     5       Sp4   Fam4     4.32     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
# 20     5       Sp4   Fam5    14.48     0         0    0    0    0    0    0
```

I need to replace some of the zero values of columns 7-11 ('Fam1' ... 'Fam5'), in accordance to the following 3-step procedure:

Step 1: For all possible pairs of 'Code1' and 'SpeciesG1' I want the Pct_feed values replacing the zero values **matching ** the family names columns in columns 7→11 (i.e., 'Fam1', 'Fam2', 'Fam3', 'Fam4'  and' Fam5'), but expanding those values horizontally (or transposing, that is, all values in the same row).

Step 2: In that same single row created in Step 1, the values of 'Code1' and 'SpeciesG1' should replace the '0' values under columns 'Code2' and ' SpeciesG2'.

Step 3: All the rows, except the single row created in Step 1, with the same pair of values of 'Code1' and 'SpeciesG1', should be deleted.

The end result of this 3-step operation, as applied to df, should look as follows:

```
#Code1   SpeciesG1   Family  Pct_feed   Code2   SpeciesG2    Fam1    Fam2    Fam3    Fam4    Fam5
#1        Sp1        Fam1     55.40     1       Sp1          55.40   12.56  1.35     30.69    0
#2        Sp1        Fam2     62.93     2       Sp1          0       62.93  37.07    0        0
#3        Sp2        Fam4     6.11      3       Sp2          0       0      0        17.49    82.51
#4        Sp2        Fam1     36.97     4       Sp2          36.97   51.46  11.57    0        0
#5        Sp3        Fam1     41.81     5       Sp3          41.81   9.64   31.74    5.12     11.69
#5        Sp4        Fam2     41.16     5       Sp4          0       41.16  40.04    4.32     14.48
```

NOTE1: As a check, the sum of all Pct_feed values of a given pair of values of 'Code1' and 'SpeciesG1' should be 100.

NOTE2: I have looked into the dplyr package, but I couldn't find a way of obtaining the results I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your output values in `Code2` is same as value in `Code1`, and same for `SpeciesG2` and `SpeciesG1`. Nonetheless, here is a code to get exact expected output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Code2 = Code1, SpeciesG2 = SpeciesG1, 
         val = Pct_feed, col = Family) %>%
  group_by(Code1, SpeciesG1) %>%
  mutate(across(c(Pct_feed, Family), first)) %>%
  ungroup%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = val, values_fill = 0)

#  Code1 SpeciesG1 Family Pct_feed Code2 SpeciesG2  Fam1  Fam2  Fam3  Fam4  Fam5
#  <int> <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <int> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 Sp1       Fam1       55.4     1 Sp1        55.4 12.6   1.35 30.7    0  
#2     2 Sp1       Fam2       62.9     2 Sp1         0   62.9  37.1   0      0  
#3     3 Sp2       Fam4       17.5     3 Sp2         0    0     0    17.5   82.5
#4     4 Sp2       Fam1       37.0     4 Sp2        37.0 51.5  11.6   0      0  
#5     5 Sp3       Fam1       41.8     5 Sp3        41.8  9.64 31.7   5.12  11.7
#6     5 Sp4       Fam2       41.2     5 Sp4         0   41.2  40.0   4.32  14.5
```

**data**

Don't pre-initialise the columns with 0 values. Keeping only the columns which has data.

```
df <- structure(list(Code1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), SpeciesG1 = c("Sp1", 
"Sp1", "Sp1", "Sp1", "Sp1", "Sp1", "Sp2", "Sp2", "Sp2", "Sp2", 
"Sp2", "Sp3", "Sp3", "Sp3", "Sp3", "Sp3", "Sp4", "Sp4", "Sp4", 
"Sp4"), Family = c("Fam1", "Fam2", "Fam3", "Fam4", "Fam2", "Fam3", 
"Fam4", "Fam5", "Fam1", "Fam2", "Fam3", "Fam1", "Fam2", "Fam3", 
"Fam4", "Fam5", "Fam2", "Fam3", "Fam4", "Fam5"), Pct_feed = c(55.4, 
12.56, 1.35, 30.69, 62.93, 37.07, 17.49, 82.51, 36.97, 51.46, 
11.57, 41.81, 9.64, 31.74, 5.12, 11.69, 41.16, 40.04, 4.32, 14.48
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Dear Ronak: Thank you very much for the suggestion and the quick answer. Using the df as created by your creation, the script gives an error:

Comment: Error: Failed to create output due to bad names.
* Choose another strategy with `names_repair`

Comment: The r error is: Error: Failed to create output due to bad names.
* Choose another strategy with `names_repair` If I delete the last line: (pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = val, values_fill = 0) that error disappears. However, even in that case the product of your suggestion does not conform to my needs. The Pct_feed values are not transposed in their respective Family columns. I needed the result that way as it is an input to another program that requires that format. Do you think that you can make that last tweak? Thank you very much again. Cordially. Jorge

Comment: Thanks again. I just updated both packages (dplyr to vers 1.0.5 and tidyr to vers 1.1.3). There is now the following error with the full script: Error in dfst %>% mutate(Code2 = Code1, SpeciesG2 = SpeciesG1, val = Pct_feed,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Dear Ronak: Thank you VERY much again, and excuse me for being sloppy. I forgot to load again the two libraries after updating, Really unforgivable ! Now your original script work marvelously. The result is exactly as I needed it !! THANKS A MILLION !

Comment: Dear Ronak: I would like to follow your suggestion and "accept the answer"; however, I do not see any "mark to the left" to click. Thank you very much.

Comment: I do not see any tick mark. I am sending you to your personal e-mail the image of my screen (screen capture) to see if I am looking in the right place).